# Setting up SSH client in Smart Git

Tags: git, bitbucket, smartgit

Here's my story, I'm not a software person; However, I'm huge fan of the fascinating world of software, and all the good in it. Through my previous employment and academic history, I have never dealt with software version control programs, let alone software development. Long story short, I got myself into this software position out of necessity to work, and although I work with wonderful and extremely helpful people who helped me set it up before, I found myself now stuck trying to set up git again. So I'm posting here as a last resort, I really hope I can resolve it since smartgit is much more intuitive and easy for me to use than git bash.

I have downloaded and installed git version 2.27.0 for windows, and SmartGit 18.1.0, and added git.exe to executables in smartgit:
[image]

Generated the SSH key and stored it in the my personal Users folder using ssh-keygen -t rsa. Then I copied the public key and added it to the Bitbucket Server, I verified it's matching and logged out then back in to make sure it takes it, I even tried to delete the browser cache in an attempt to resolve the problem below.

For the first clone, I was told that I must first clone from GIT Bash prior to cloning from SmartGIT for the first time. The clone wasn't allowed at first, I discovered there was an .ssh folder created in the c drive, after coping the key there it allows a clone (using the command git clone ssh...), but it's missing a sub-module from the repository. I execute the following commands and that sub-module gets updated with the most recent files:

[image]

I go to smart git: Remote -> Submodule -> initialize and pull, and Success it works!

I try to pull and it works as well. However, when I try to change the Authentication in Preferences to use SmartGit as SSH client,

[image]
and then try to pull, it fails and gives this reason
[image]

When I try to clone a new repo in smartgit while setting the Authentication in Preferences to use system SSH client, it clones the repo but misses that submodule.
When I try to clone a new repo in smartgit while setting the Authentication in Preferences to use Smartgit as SSH client, I get an error regarding not being able to read from the same sub-module which was missing from the clone mentioned earlier.

[image]

I am positive that I have access rights to that sub-module and that it exists, and I think the fact that I was able to check it out using the commands proves the same. I would appreciate any help or suggestions or suggestions regarding why smartgit is not allowed to read that submodule. Did I miss something in the setup? Thank you so much.

Comment: First step will be to switch back to "Use system SSH client" (i.e. take SmartGit out of the loop as much as possible). After that try to get the exact command which fails from SmartGit working from terminal. Although this page is about HTTP, many of the steps apply for SSH, too: https://www.syntevo.com/doc/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6979745